# Logout issue in firefox in blazor server app

Tags: firefox, blazor-server-side, autologin, duende-identity-server, third-party-cookies

I experience logout issue in Firefox browser. This is what happens:

- Click logout
- It logged out because I do not see member menu anymore.
- I click on login button. The login button opens the login form in an iframe on the screen.
- Rather then seeing login form, I automatically login.

When login occurs, cookies are written from the page in the iframe. How can deleted cookies be automatically rewritten after logout? (Note: This problem only occurs in Firefox. In Chrome and Edge browsers, there is no such issue.)

What I've done to try to identify the root cause of the problem:

```
• There is no automatic login problem when the login iframe is opened after closing and 
  opening the browser.

• I copied the src of the login iframe and opened it in a new window. Then I logged in 
  and logged out. When I opened the login iframe again, there was no automatic 
  login."So this problem only occurs when the login process is done with iframe."

• I found that different tabs are treated differently until the next authentication state checks. Please see this post: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73802938/how-to-logout-from-a-blazor-server-app-with-multiple-open-browser-tabs][1]

• After some investigation, I found that Firefox(unlike other browsers) blocks "Cross- 
  site" cookies in the factory settings. When I disabled this setting, the problem was 
  solved.
```

I can see that cookies are deleted after logout in the browser. So how could this problem be caused by blocking third party cookies?